# LazyLoad Module in Angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ng-modules

I am following this blog for
[Lazy Lodaing a Module](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html)

Everything is fine except the part when it asks me to assign static path for the module to be loaded.

the name of the module will depend on the users choice as i may have a number of modules

how can i assign a variable to loadChildren in routing and how to create this variable just before routing

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Ahead of Time compilation you can try passing a function to `loadChildren`:

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: () => 'lazy/lazy.module#' + dynamicModuleName }
```

Comment: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildren'.

Comment: Well, it'd be possible if you were using [ng-router-loader](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-router-loader)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define your [custom module loader](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/optimizing-app-loading-time-with-angular-2-lazy-loading).

Another option is to use default exports. Since router uses the following code:

```
  private loadAndCompile(path: string): Promise<NgModuleFactory<any>> {
    let [module, exportName] = path.split(_SEPARATOR);
    if (exportName === undefined) {
      exportName = 'default';
    }
```

to load a module, you can export default module and don't pass any module name at all:

```
export default class MyModule {}
```

Comment: getting this error, 
Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildren'.

Comment: is this the error you're getting with solution or Daniel's?

Comment: yes.
well is thr any other way to lazyLoad my module or even component.
I have more that 500 forms, each form is a component i want to load a form on request. So the route of the component will be decided upon users choice

Comment: create a plunker please

Comment: till now i have not been able to solve. I am thinking of using ui-router, there i might be able to define path or maybe i will one object to routes array via backend code(text file editting, though i dont know the implications for that. I guess it will cause the server to restart)

Comment: @AnkitRaonka, ui-router is for angularjs AFAIK

Comment: thr is ng2-ui-router for angular i guess

Comment: @yurzui loadChildren takes a string as path and if assign a function it should return a promise